# Calling C function from lua

Tags: c, lua

Can someone tell me is it possible to somehow call c function or simply wrap it into a lua function WITHOUT building a new module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lua can't call arbitrary C functions - they have to be bound to something in the Lua namespace first. (This is intentional to prevent breaking out of sandboxes in embedded applications.)

Comment: so as far as I  understand I have two ways to solve this problem: first - run lua script from C, and than wrap C functions and push them into a stack, and second - build a new module for lua. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. You can dynamically bind C functions via the C API, or you can create a module that does that binding.

Answer (score 6):

If it works for you, try the [FFI library](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html). See also [luaffi](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-07/msg00467.html).

Answer (score 3):

Or the [Alien](http://alien.luaforge.net/) library.